# Operating System:Difference between Paging and Caching

Tags: caching, paging

Is paging a mapping between Main and Secondary Memory and Caching a mapping between Main and Cache Memory?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question. This appears to be a conceptual question about operating system design, more suitable to http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: can't we post any conceptual ques in stackoverflow ? I did earlier

Comment: SO is supposed to be for programming questions.